# Multiple token authentication Android

Tags: android

I am looking for advise on the best approach for multiple token authentication in android.

What I mean by this is, I have to private API calls to 2 different logins which both will require authentication and in return provide a auth token.

Is it possible for me to create a single login for my app with will in turn prompt a subsequent login to both these other API calls and then store their respective tokens?

Or is there another method which will do what I want and is more efficient.

Thanks for any advise

Dave

Comment: are you controlling both sides of the 2 logins? i.e. are those facebook/google type of authentication, or an authentication with your own custom service/website?

Comment: So its for two seperate IoT devices, one will be smart heating solution via API calls and the second will be smart devices around the home, only problem is both have to be authorised through two custom websites.

Comment: you can perhaps have a single login with your backend server, and have the server authenticate with those two services on behalf of the user. Whether that's possible or not is really service dependent.